# how to use angular-translate-loader-static-files in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angular-translate

i installed `angular-translate-loader-static-files` with this command line `bower install angular-translate-loader-static-files`

after ,i create a file json with this name `messages_en.json` in folder `i18n`

my angular.module like this:

```
   angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngStorage', 'ngCordova','starter.services','ionic-datepicker','starter.directives','ion-google-place','ngAutocomplete','colorpicker.module','ui.calendar','ngLoadingSpinner','ionic-ratings','pascalprecht.translate'])

facebookExample.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {

     $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
            prefix: 'i18n/messages_',
            suffix: '.json'
          });

        $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
        $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("en");
});
```

in my index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
```

my messages_en.json:

```
{
    "Accueil" : "welcome",
    "Livre" : "book",

}
```

but when i run my application the word 'Livre' not translate into English

what's the problem please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your json file. Remove the last comma and you should be OK.

Note : Don't add angular-translate-loader-static-files.js and angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js. Choose only one to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the follow code to get en error message, if your JSON-File is invalid

```js
$scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
    $translate.use(langKey).then(function(){}, function(){toastr.error('JSON file is invalid')})
};
```